# Difference in model object returned by caret vs. base

Tags: r, r-caret

I have equivalent models from base r and caret:

```
base_lm <- lm(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars)

library(caret)
caret_lm <- train(
  mpg ~ cyl,
  data = mtcars,
  method = "lm"
)
```

I wanted to use the statisticalModelling package with my linear model from caret:

```
statisticalModeling::evaluate_model(caret_lm)
Error in UseMethod("explanatory_vars") : 
  no applicable method for 'explanatory_vars' applied to an object of class "c('train', 'train.formula')"
```

The tried:

```
statisticalModeling::evaluate_model(caret_lm$finalModel)
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'dat' not found
```

It does with with base r linear model

```
statisticalModeling::evaluate_model(base_lm)

  cyl model_output
1   0    37.884576
2   5    23.505626
3  10     9.126675
```

Is there a way to use caret models with statistical modelling package?

Comment: Is `lm_mod$finalModel` what you are looking for? Otherwise, a reproducible example would help.

Comment: Hi @DavidHeckmann, updated question with reproducible example. Not sure if this is possible but would certainly be convenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `finalModel` slot of the train object and specify the data to predict explicitly:

```
pred_base <- evaluate_model(base_lm , data = mtcars[,1:2])

pred_caret <- evaluate_model(caret_lm$finalModel , data = mtcars[,1:2])
# compare predictions:
all( pred_base$model_output == pred_caret$model_output )
[1] TRUE
```